# Динамические свойства у ссылочного типа c# BindingList

Tags: c#, синхронизация, свойства

Объявляю свойства

```
    public static bool isOnline = false;
    public static BindingList<Request> OnlineRequests { get; set; } = new BindingList<Request>();

    public static BindingList<Request> CachedRequests { get; set; } = new BindingList<Request>();

    public static BindingList<Request> Requests { get
        {
            if (isOnline)
            {
                return OnlineRequests;
            }
            else
            {
                return CachedRequests;
            }
        } set
        {
            if (isOnline) 
            {
                OnlineRequests = value;
            }
            else
            {
                CachedRequests = value;
            }
        } }
```

Потом в Main

```
        gridRequest.DataSource = Config.Requests;
        Requests.ListChanged += requests_ListChanged;
```

DataSource мгновенно не изменяется при изменении переменной **isOnline** (требуется повторная привязка). **Event ListChanged** не срабатывает никогда

Вопрос. Возможно ли как-то синхронизировать всю логику, обращаясь исключительно к **Requests**

Comment: Привязали свойство, которое постоянно меняете в коде - вызывайте у него `INotifyPropertyChanged`, которое оповестит привязки о том, что оно обновилось.

Comment: Немного недопонял вариант Ваш

Comment: Сейчас я решил реализовать другой вариант.       

private void requests_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Requests.RaiseListChangedEvents) return;
....

Грубая привязка обоих Event ListChanged  к этому методу и проверка, срабатывает ли Event в основной Requests

Comment: Ну, начнем с того, что статика зло, ее быть не должно. Далее, почему `Requests` это свойство, а не метод? Если у вас там еще и асинхронные задачи, где вы кэщируете серверные данные, то вообще это должно быть `ValueTask`. Ну и последнее, если `gridRequest.DataSource` - это UI контрол, то сделайте к нему правильную **привязку** (зависит от типа проекта), а свойства обновляйте через `INotifyPropertyChanged` (в интернете полно реализаций и примеров), тогда вам не нужны будут события и что либо еще.

Comment: Использую статику исключительно потому что делаю рефакторинг. Слишком много переписывать, если делать все "правильно". Про остальное почитаю, спасибо

Comment: **см. ссылку на дубликат.** Вам нужно свойство `public BindingList<Request> Requests => IsOnline? OnlineRequests : CachedRequests;` (никаких `static` быть не должно!) далее при изменении свойства `IsOnline` в сеттере вызвать `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Requests))`.

Answer (score -1):

Не углубляясь далеко, можно сказать, что изменение данных работает в одном направлении: Элемент управления для отображения и изменения данных (например, DataGridView) --> BindingList (или BindingSource) --> источник данных. Можно, конечно, плыть против течения, сильно гребя руками, а можно работать с BindingList.